# slice_min returning NA if with_ties FALSE

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, minimum

I have difficulties to understand the logic behind the following behavior of the dplyr function `slice_min`

```
my_data <- data.frame(a = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), 
                      b = c(1, 1, 2, 3, NA))

#Try to return the minimum of b, for each group of a
my_data %>% group_by(a) %>%
  slice_min(b, with_ties = TRUE)

#># A tibble: 3 × 2
#># Groups:   a [2]
#>  a         b
#>  <fct> <dbl>
#>1 a         1
#>2 a         1
#>3 b         2

#Doing the same, but avoid ties (like in the case of a)
my_data %>% group_by(a) %>%
  slice_min(b, with_ties = FALSE)

#>  a         b
#>  <fct> <dbl>
#>1 a         1
#>2 b         2
#>3 c        NA
```

My question: Why is NA returned if I omit ties, but not when I allow ties? Is this a bug or can anybody explain to me the logic behind this behavior?

Comment: Probably a bug.  If you check the source code [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/slice.R), the `with_ties = FALSE` is just taking the `head` `idx <- function(x, n) head(order(x), size(n))` whereas the other is using `dx <- function(x, n) head(order(x), smaller_ranks(x, size(n)))` which uses `min_rank` and other functions in `smaller_ranks`.  Also, in `slice_min`, by default `n = 1`.  So i am guessing that the `head` with n = 1 doesn't drop the 'c' with `NA` when you have with_ties = FALSE, whereas for the other case, `smaller_ranks` would be returning 0 as NA is dropped

Comment: The key is the `smaller_ranks` i.e. `smaller_ranks <- function(x, y) {
  sum(min_rank(x) <= y, na.rm = TRUE)
}`. Suppose you have only `NA` then `sum(NA <= 5, na.rm = TRUE)` returns 0.  y can be any value